# Is this sentence correct and natural?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct and does it sound natural?

> Basement is where the wrecked useless stuff end up.

P.S. this is not a part of a broader context, this is from a short story I'm trying to write in English.

Comment: There are alternate sites available for proofreading, such as [Lang-8](http://lang-8.com/).

Comment: @snailboat That sounds great. Thank you. I'd definitely check that out.

Comment: @snailboat, I don't think this question is not good for ELL. I myself had a little doubt about these constructs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would sound better as "**The** basement is where the wrecked, useless stuff **ends** up."

You would use *the* with basement because you are specifying which basement. *Ends* is used with *stuff*, because *stuff* is actually singular.

> The useless things end up in the basement. (*Things* is plural.)

> The useless stuff ends up in the basement. (*Stuff* is singular.)